# What kind of English does Hagrid speak?

Tags: harry-potter, languages, hagrid

Through all the books Hagrid speaks a bit oddly. He changes word order, skips letters/parts of words or merges words. Is this some kind of specific dialect or accent?

> "Won't make no diff'rence!" sobbed Hagrid. "Them Disposal devils, they're all in Lucius Malfoy's pocket! Scared o' him! An' if I lose the case, Buckbeak-"
>   *<sub>- The Prisoner of Azkaban, Chapter 11: The Firebolt</sub>*

Comment: Olde Hagrish? :)

Comment: The on'y kind!!

Answer (score 48, accepted):

From a [Blue Peter BBC interview with JK Rowling](http://www.accio-quote.org/articles/2001/0301-bluepeter.htm) in 2001:

> **BPP2:** Good question, good question. I've got another good question
>   here ... what accent is Hagrid supposed to speak in?
>
> **JKR:** [West country](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/West_Country) ... where I come from, I come from the West country.
>
> **BPP3:** So now we know.

So Hagrid is intended to have a West Country accent.

Comment: N-not Scottish? Blimey, I've been reading wrong all this time XD

Comment: I'm from Bristol, and I always read it as a Bristolian accent, Robbie Coltrane really pulls it off in the movies too :p

Comment: yeah, west country accent is pretty identifiable once you hear it. Play Fable some time.

Comment: I've heard that in spite of being (geographically) much smaller, the U.K. has a great many more dialects/varieties of English than the U.S.

Comment: @JoeL.: You have heard correctly. Parts of the UK have had stable English-speaking communities for 700 years or so, that's a long time for distinctive regional dialects to develop. Modern travel and communciation have reduced the diversity somewhat but there's still a lot of variation.

Comment: @JoeL. You are correct, you can travel <350 miles (Bristol -> Birmingham -> Liverpool -> Manchester -> Durham) and see such a wide variety of dialect!

Comment: Having already displayed my stupidity (:P) I must shower you all in my tremendous and entirely relevant knowledge that cows too have regional dialects (not even making this up)